# What causes a dot to be printed upon every ssh login?

Tags: ssh, login

For example:

```
brianbi@local:~$ ssh root@remote
root@remote's password: 
.Linux remote 2.6.32-042stab113.21 #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 11:05:25 MSK 2016 i686

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have mail.
Last login: Sat May 13 22:43:25 2017 from (redacted)
```

The dot is at the very beginning, before the uname and motd are printed.

The dot gets printed regardless of which user account I log into, and regardless of where I ssh from. Also, ~/.hushlogin doesn't prevent it from being printed.

If I do

```
ssh root@remote /bin/true
```

then only the dot is printed (and then the session closes).

What could explain this?

Comment: Startup scripts, Motd, many possibilities.

Comment: Run `ssh` in the most verbose mode, i.e. `ssh -vvv root@remote` and you'll get more information to investigate this.

Comment: @EsaJokinen It prints a lot of stuff, and finally "debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0" and then the dot and the usual stuff.